# UICollectionView custom line separators

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I wanna making **2pt black separators** in `UICollectionView` for our new app. Screenshot from our app is below. We couldn't use `UITableView`, because we have custom insert/delete animations, scrolling and parallax effects and so on.

[image: Example]

Comment: There has just got to be an easier way ...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I started with three ideas how to make it:

- implement these separators right **inside the cells**
- use **solid black background** with `minimumLineSpacing`, thus we will see background in spaces between cells
- use **custom layout** and implement this separators as decorations

First two variants were rejected because ideologic inconsistency, custom animations and having content below collection. Also I already have a custom layout.

I will describe the steps with a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

### --1--

Implement custom `UICollectionReusableView` subclass.

```
@interface FLCollectionSeparator : UICollectionReusableView

@end

@implementation FLCollectionSeparator

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes {
    self.frame = layoutAttributes.frame;
}

@end
```

### --2--

Say layout to use custom decorations. Also make line spacing between cells.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) self.newsCollection.collectionViewLayout;
[layout registerClass:[FLCollectionSeparator class] forDecorationViewOfKind:@"Separator"];
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2;
```

### --3--

In custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass we should return `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for decorations from `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    ... collect here layout attributes for cells ... 

    NSMutableArray *decorationAttributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [self indexPathsOfSeparatorsInRect:rect]; // will implement below

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visibleIndexPaths) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:@"Separator" atIndexPath:indexPath];
        [decorationAttributes addObject:attributes];
    }

    return [layoutAttributesArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:decorationAttributes];
}
```

### --4--

For visible rect we should return visible decorations index pathes.

```
- (NSArray*)indexPathsOfSeparatorsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSInteger firstCellIndexToShow = floorf(rect.origin.y / self.itemSize.height);
    NSInteger lastCellIndexToShow = floorf((rect.origin.y + CGRectGetHeight(rect)) / self.itemSize.height);
    NSInteger countOfItems = [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];

    NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = MAX(firstCellIndexToShow, 0); i <= lastCellIndexToShow; i++) {
        if (i < countOfItems) {
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }
    }
    return indexPaths;
}
```

### --5--

Also we should implement `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind`.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString *)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:decorationViewKind withIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat decorationOffset = (indexPath.row + 1) * self.itemSize.height + indexPath.row * self.minimumLineSpacing;
    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, decorationOffset, self.collectionViewContentSize.width, self.minimumLineSpacing);
    layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1000;

    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

### --6--

Sometimes I found that this solution gives visual glitches with decorations appearance, which was fixed with implementing `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind`.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)decorationIndexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes =  [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:elementKind atIndexPath:decorationIndexPath];
    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

That's all. Not too much code but done right.

Comment: is there a way to prevent the line from showing up if there are now rows beyond the first few. It seems that the lines are generated regardless of whether or not there is content

Comment: @CoderNinja you should look at step 4 where we get `numberOfItemsInSection` from datasource, so separators should be showing only if you have cell content

Answer (score 21):

***Quick solution in Swift***

**1. Create CustomFlowLayout.swift file and paste next code**

```
import UIKit

private let separatorDecorationView = "separator"

final class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        register(SeparatorView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) ?? []
        let lineWidth = self.minimumLineSpacing

        var decorationAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

        // skip first cell
        for layoutAttribute in layoutAttributes where layoutAttribute.indexPath.item > 0 {
            let separatorAttribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView,
                                                                      with: layoutAttribute.indexPath)
            let cellFrame = layoutAttribute.frame
            separatorAttribute.frame = CGRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x,
                                              y: cellFrame.origin.y - lineWidth,
                                              width: cellFrame.size.width,
                                              height: lineWidth)
            separatorAttribute.zIndex = Int.max
            decorationAttributes.append(separatorAttribute)
        }

        return layoutAttributes + decorationAttributes
    }

}

private final class SeparatorView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        self.frame = layoutAttributes.frame
    }
}
```

**2. Setup custom flow**

In the interface builder select your UICollectionViewFlow and set our new class name `CustomFlowLayout`

**3. Change a separator color**

In SeparatorView you can change the color of separator in `init`

**4. Change a height of the separator**

You can do it in two different ways

- In the storyboboard. Change a property `Min Spacing for Lines`

OR

- In the code. Set value for `minimumLineSpacing`

  ```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      register(SeparatorView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView)
      minimumLineSpacing = 2 }
  ```

Comment: Small tip: If you are inserting and deleting cells, it's easier to use `.isHidden` and  `.alpha` instead of sparing the decorator at index 0.

Comment: `awakeFromNib` is not even called when doing UI programmatically so registering the decorator and specifying the spacing must be done after creating the FlowLayout.

Comment: For programmatically use needs to `awakeFromNib` change to : override init() { super.init() register(SeparatorView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView) minimumLineSpacing = 2 } required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

Answer (score 14):

Excellent suggestion by Anton, but I think the implementation in the FlowLayout sub class can be even simpler. Because the super implementation of - (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect already returns the layout attributes of the cells including their frame and indexPath you have enough info to calculate the frames of the separators by overriding only this method and introspecting the cell layout attributes:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *layoutAttributesArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    CGFloat lineWidth = self.minimumLineSpacing;
    NSMutableArray *decorationAttributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:layoutAttributesArray.count];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesArray) {
        //Add separator for every row except the first
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath;
        if (indexPath.item > 0) {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *separatorAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:kCellSeparatorKind withIndexPath:indexPath];
            CGRect cellFrame = layoutAttributes.frame;

            //In my case I have a horizontal grid, where I need vertical separators, but the separator frame can be calculated as needed
            //e.g. top, or both top and left
            separatorAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x - lineWidth, cellFrame.origin.y, lineWidth, cellFrame.size.height);
            separatorAttributes.zIndex = 1000;
            [decorationAttributes addObject:separatorAttributes];
        }
    }
    return [layoutAttributesArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:decorationAttributes];
}
```

Comment: This is a great additional answer. The accepted answer is totally correct, but in almost all cases you can use this approach to _vastly_ simplify step 3 & 4, and skip step 5 entirely! The trick with UICV layout is doing as little of it as possible.

Comment: I used this as a nice simplification along with the accepted answer, and it works great!

Comment: This seems to work only, if you do not insert or delete cells. Then you have to implement `func layoutAttributesForXXXView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)` as well

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Anton & Werner, both helped me out - I've taken your help to make a drag & drop solution, as a category on `UICollectionView`, thought I'd share the results:

**UICollectionView+Separators.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UICollectionView (Separators)

@property (nonatomic) BOOL sep_useCellSeparators;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *sep_separatorColor;

@end
```

**UICollectionView+Separators.m**

```
#import "UICollectionView+Separators.h"
@import ObjectiveC;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark -

@interface UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes (SEPLayoutAttributes)

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *sep_separatorColor;

@end

@implementation UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes (SEPLayoutAttributes)

- (void)setSep_separatorColor:(UIColor *)sep_separatorColor
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sep_separatorColor), sep_separatorColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (UIColor *)sep_separatorColor
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sep_separatorColor));
}

@end

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark -

@interface SEPCollectionViewCellSeparatorView : UICollectionReusableView

@end

@implementation SEPCollectionViewCellSeparatorView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    self.frame = layoutAttributes.frame;

    if (layoutAttributes.sep_separatorColor != nil)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = layoutAttributes.sep_separatorColor;
    }
}

@end

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark -

static NSString *const kCollectionViewCellSeparatorReuseId = @"kCollectionViewCellSeparatorReuseId";

@implementation UICollectionViewFlowLayout (SEPCellSeparators)

#pragma mark - Setters/getters

- (void)setSep_separatorColor:(UIColor *)sep_separatorColor
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sep_separatorColor), sep_separatorColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    [self invalidateLayout];
}

- (UIColor *)sep_separatorColor
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sep_separatorColor));
}

- (void)setSep_useCellSeparators:(BOOL)sep_useCellSeparators
{
    if (self.sep_useCellSeparators != sep_useCellSeparators)
    {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sep_useCellSeparators), @(sep_useCellSeparators), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

        [self registerClass:[SEPCollectionViewCellSeparatorView class] forDecorationViewOfKind:kCollectionViewCellSeparatorReuseId];
        [self invalidateLayout];
    }
}

- (BOOL)sep_useCellSeparators
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sep_useCellSeparators)) boolValue];
}

#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swizzle_layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)swizzle_layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *layoutAttributesArray = [self swizzle_layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    if (self.sep_useCellSeparators == NO)
    {
        return layoutAttributesArray;
    }

    CGFloat lineSpacing = self.minimumLineSpacing;

    NSMutableArray *decorationAttributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:layoutAttributesArray.count];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesArray)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath;

        if (indexPath.item > 0)
        {
            id <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> delegate = (id <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>)self.collectionView.delegate;
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:)])
            {
                lineSpacing = [delegate collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            }

            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *separatorAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:kCollectionViewCellSeparatorReuseId withIndexPath:indexPath];
            CGRect cellFrame = layoutAttributes.frame;

            if (self.scrollDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal)
            {
                separatorAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x - lineSpacing, cellFrame.origin.y, lineSpacing, cellFrame.size.height);
            }
            else
            {
                separatorAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x, cellFrame.origin.y - lineSpacing, cellFrame.size.width, lineSpacing);
            }

            separatorAttributes.zIndex = 1000;

            separatorAttributes.sep_separatorColor = self.sep_separatorColor;

            [decorationAttributes addObject:separatorAttributes];
        }
    }

    return [layoutAttributesArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:decorationAttributes];
}

@end

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark -

@implementation UICollectionView (Separators)

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)sep_flowLayout
{
    if ([self.collectionViewLayout isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewFlowLayout class]])
    {
        return (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)setSep_separatorColor:(UIColor *)sep_separatorColor
{
    [self.sep_flowLayout setSep_separatorColor:sep_separatorColor];
}

- (UIColor *)sep_separatorColor
{
    return [self.sep_flowLayout sep_separatorColor];
}

- (void)setSep_useCellSeparators:(BOOL)sep_useCellSeparators
{
    [self.sep_flowLayout setSep_useCellSeparators:sep_useCellSeparators];
}

- (BOOL)sep_useCellSeparators
{
    return [self.sep_flowLayout sep_useCellSeparators];
}

@end
```

Using Objective-C runtime and some **swizzling**, cell separators can be added with a couple of lines to any existing `UICollectionView` whose layout is/inherits from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

**Example Usage:**

```
#import "UICollectionView+Separators.h"
...
self.collectionView.sep_useCellSeparators = YES;
self.collectionView.sep_separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

A couple notes:

- Separator height/width can be determined per section, using `collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:`, falling back on `minimumLineSpacing` if not implemented
- Built to handle horizontal or vertical scroll direction

Hope it helps

Comment: Also obv be careful when Swizzling - this just happened to be very convenient on my project that used lots of different collection views & subclasses of Flow Layout

Comment: I'm not a fan of mixing underscores with camel case in Objective C and Swift. I'm not sure why you even need the sep_ prefix. 

And the abbreviations may make sense to you (now), but other developers will have a cognitive load when reading your code, and you may too in future.

Comment: Thanks, while I understand your reasoning, I find it is best practice to use such prefixes on class categories to ensure distinguishability and avoid any possible conflict

Comment: In general this works well, however I find it crashes if you perform actions such as deleting cells `[tabsCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [tabEntries removeObjectAtIndex: cellToClose.cellIndex];
        [tabsCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths: @[removedIndexPath]];
    } completion: NULL];` (with no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKindOfKind: kCollectionViewCellSeparatorReuseId at path ...).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version from Anton Gaenko but implemented in C#, this could be usefull for Xamarin users :

```
[Register(nameof(FLCollectionSeparator))]
public class FLCollectionSeparator : UICollectionReusableView
{
    public FLCollectionSeparator(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
    }
    public FLCollectionSeparator(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
    }
    public override void ApplyLayoutAttributes(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributes)
    {
        this.Frame = layoutAttributes.Frame;
    }
}

[Register(nameof(UILinedSpacedViewFlowLayout))]
public class UILinedSpacedViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    public const string SeparatorAttribute = "Separator";
    private static readonly NSString NSSeparatorAttribute = new NSString(SeparatorAttribute);
    public UILinedSpacedViewFlowLayout() : base() { this.InternalInit(); }
    public UILinedSpacedViewFlowLayout(NSCoder coder) : base (coder) { this.InternalInit(); }
    protected UILinedSpacedViewFlowLayout(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t) { this.InternalInit(); }
    private void InternalInit()
    {
        this.RegisterClassForDecorationView(typeof(FLCollectionSeparator), NSSeparatorAttribute);
    }
    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        return LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect_internal(rect).ToArray();
    }
    private IEnumerable<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes> LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect_internal(CGRect rect)
    {
        foreach (var baseDecorationAttr in base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect))
        {
            yield return baseDecorationAttr;
        }
        foreach (var indexPath in this.IndexPathsOfSeparatorsInRect(rect))
        {
            yield return this.LayoutAttributesForDecorationView(NSSeparatorAttribute, indexPath);
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<NSIndexPath> IndexPathsOfSeparatorsInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        int firstCellIndexToShow = (int)(rect.Y / this.ItemSize.Height);
        int lastCellIndexToShow  = (int)((rect.Y + rect.Height) / this.ItemSize.Height);
        int countOfItems = (int)this.CollectionView.DataSource.GetItemsCount(this.CollectionView, 0);
        for (int i = Math.Max(firstCellIndexToShow, 0); i <= lastCellIndexToShow; i++)
        {
            if (i < countOfItems)
            {
                yield return NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes LayoutAttributesForDecorationView(NSString kind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributes = base.LayoutAttributesForDecorationView(kind, indexPath);
        var decorationOffset = (indexPath.Row + 1) * this.ItemSize.Height + indexPath.Row * this.MinimumLineSpacing + this.HeaderReferenceSize.Height;
        layoutAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForDecorationView(kind, indexPath);
        layoutAttributes.Frame = new CGRect(0, decorationOffset, this.CollectionViewContentSize.Width, this.MinimumLineSpacing);
        layoutAttributes.ZIndex = 1000;
        return layoutAttributes;
    }
    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes InitialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElement(NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath decorationIndexPath)
    {
        return base.InitialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElement(elementKind, decorationIndexPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a gist with another implementation for line separators which supports UICollectionView with one or more columns and sections for xamarin people: https://gist.github.com/TobiasBuchholz/f813ccfd021dac7d0f0bf69f440f9ca9

Answer (score 2):

In @SlavikVoloshyn answer for programmatically use this section:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    register(SeparatorView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView)
}
```

needs to change to :

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    register(SeparatorView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView)
    minimumLineSpacing = 2
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```